# access a richtextblock inside button control template in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, richtextbox

I developing an app fro windows phone 7 using C#.
I would like to access a richtextbox which is inside a button template but for some reason VS2010 is not recognizing the richtextblock

```
<Button Name="btnFrom" Click="SetFromCurrency">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <RichTextBox x:Name="FromTxtBx" IsReadOnly="True" Height="55" Margin="15,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="185" Foreground="White" Background="White"   />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

When I type for example FromTxtBx.Text the compiler give me an error saying (The name 'FromTxtBx' does not exist in the current context)

Can anyone give me the correct way to access the richtextbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should have `ContentPresenter` element inside `ControlTemplate` and then put your RichTextBox in that `ContentPresenter`

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer">
       <ContentPresenter ></ContentPresenter>
</ContentControl>
```

After that you could access to the content of your button control using `Content` property.
For example:

```
if( (btnFrom.Content as RichTextBox) != null)
{
    (btnFrom.Content as RichTextBox).IsReadOnly = false;
}
```